# Can I use Java to develop gui for ubuntu

Tags: application-development

I'm developing a GUI for Ubuntu using Quickly tool. I'm not familiar with python so can I use Java/C++/C# programming languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Quickly (software)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickly_%28software%29)
>
> Quickly is a framework for creating software programs for a Linux
> distribution using Python, PyGTK, Glade Interface Designer and Desktop
> Couch. It then allows for easy publishing using bzr and Launchpad.

As stated in the source above Quickly is designed to make applications strictly using the Python programming language and does not support Java, C++, or C#.

If you want to develop GUI applications for these programming languages I suggest you look at [Swing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_%28Java%29), [GTK](http://www.gtk.org/), or [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) for Java and GTK/Qt for C++ and C#.

Comment: Notice GTK also has java bindings http://java-gnome.sourceforge.net/ , as well as Qt does http://qtjambi.org/

Comment: @alci Thank you, I was no aware of this, I will add it to my answer.

Comment: @MichaelLindman thanks man I'll look into swing.